# Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS using GCD dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I've got a crash in my app, and only have this report:

```
9   Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x06fec000

0   MyApp   cv::Canny(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int, bool)
1
2   MyApp   MyViewController.mm line 613 myBackgroundFunction(UIImage*, std::__1::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::__1::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >&, cv::Size_<int>)
3   MyApp   MyViewController.mm line 128 __43-[MyViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke
4   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 668
```

The function `myBackgroundFunction` is being called in this GCD structure:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    cv::vector<cv::Point> rectangle1, rectangle2;      
    rectangle1 = [self detectEdgesforImage:_sourceImage1];
    rectangle2 = [self detectEdgesforImage:_sourceImage2];

    if (rectangle1.size() == 4 && rectangle2.size() == 4)
    {
        // do some other calculations            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (area1 > area2) {
                [self doStuffThisRectangle:rectangle1];
            }
            else {
                [self doStuffThisRectangle:rectangle2];
            }
        });
    }
    else if (rectangle1.size() == 4) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self doStuffThisRectangle:rectangle1];
        });
    }
    else if (rectangle2.size() == 4) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self doStuffThisRectangle:rectangle2];
        });
    }
    else {
        rectangle1.clear();            
        CGSize targetSize = _sourceImageView.contentSize;

        //time consuming function
        myBackgroundFunction(_sourceImage1, rectangle1, cvSize(targetSize.width, targetSize.height));

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (rectangle1.size() == 4) {
                [self doStuffThisRectangle:rectangle1];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

All the variables used in the `cv::Canny` call are created locally within `myBackgroundFunction` so this line in the report is confusing me.

My guess is that `_sourceImage1` was released before the block ended its execution, therefore the BAD_ACCESS.

_sourceImage1 is declared as a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *sourceImage1, *sourceImage2;
```

because the other parameters are declared within the `dispatch_async` block.

I'm not sure how to reproduce this issue or how I could fix it, if either copying somehow the UIImage, or using the `__block` modifier, but I'm quite new to this concepts and don't fully understand them.

Comment: See [My App crashed. Now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) (especially the section about zombie objects in part 2).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about zombies. But in this case, the problem is that the crash report is from a beta user, and I don't know how to reproduce this error...

Comment: You appear to have redacted frame #1 of the backtrace, which makes it harder to say.

Comment: actually that frame came empty from the bug report utility

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Nope, not really. But it didn't reproduce again AFAIK